# No response from Node.js w Express while running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, rest, reactjs, raspberry-pi, redux

So I'm running it on port 8080. Port forwarding has been set up and it is working.

Every time I type in my no-ip domain, I get the response on the screen but when I'm making a request from my website, it logs the request on the Raspberry, yet, there is no response visible in the Chrome developer tools.

I also get this error message: POST *"name of the api"* net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

What could cause that? My routes worked perfectly when I was running my api locally.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', requireAuth, function(req, res) {
    res.send({ message: 'OMG, You made it, you deserve a drink!' });
  });
```

That's how my react app looks like:

```
 const ROOT_URL = *"name of the api"/*;
.
.
.

    export function fetchMessage() {
      return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get(ROOT_URL, {
          headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }
        })
          .then(response => {
            dispatch({
              type: FETCH_MESSAGE,
              payload: response.data.message
            });
      });
  }
};
```

Is it a typical problem of the Node.js, Express, React or maybe it's on the Raspi? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a CORS issue, since the problem only happens when trying to consume the API from the browser. A possible solution is to use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package in your Express application:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

...

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

...
```

NOTE: this enables all CORS requests.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it today. I was wondering that maybe it's a security issue for not having https certificate or so.

Comment: No, I added Cors but it's unfortunately still not working.